# How can I suggest edits to Stack Overflow Blog posts?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, blog

Kevin Henner's [*An intuitive introduction to text embeddings*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/11/09/an-intuitive-introduction-to-text-embeddings/) (2023-11-09) is a very impressive write-up, except for one paragraph near the beginning, which unceremoniously demolishes the analogy that the past six paragraphs so carefully established:

> It’s easy enough to add one more term for a (*dog*x*, caty, caninez*, *feline*i) The next term, though, will break our spatial locality metaphor. We have to build a series of new libraries down the street. And if you’re looking for books with just one more or one fewer “feline” mention, they’re not right there on the shelf anymore—you’ve have to walk down the block to the next library.

This paragraph also appears to contain punctuation and formatting errors. I suspect it was left half-finished, then missed during a later editing pass. Since it's not obvious what this paragraph *should* say, any edits probably need input from the original author. (I, for example, would replace the last two sentences with “, because libraries exist in three-dimensional space.” – but that's a rather opinionated edit.)

On the other end of the scale, we have [*CEO update: Giving thanks and building upon our product & engineering foundation*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/11/15/ceo-update-giving-thanks-and-building-upon-our-product-and-engineering-foundation/) (2023-11-15), which isn't saying anything particularly fancy, but is very hard to read. Apparently someone's observed Stack Overflow's behaviour, and determined that it develops AI offerings: that's a rather odd remark for the CEO to make… unless that's *determined* (adj) in the active voice:

> 77% of developers are favorable of AI tools, but only 42% trust the accuracy of those tools. To address this, Stack Overflow’s been determined to develop AI offerings that are highly trusted and attributed in the knowledge base of 58 million asked and answered questions on the platform and proprietary knowledge within Stack Overflow for Teams.

And I think this is supposed to be a list, but the em-dash abuse makes it ungrammatical.

> The road we take together over the coming months will help us prioritize the continued growth of Stack Overflow for Teams accelerated by our GenAI offering—OverflowAI—the addition of valuable new experiences on our Stack Overflow public platform through OverflowAI, and the expansion of our strategic partnerships.

This could do with a *lot* of fairly simple copyediting, requiring little input from the original author(s). If it were posted on Meta, that would happen as a matter of course, but I don't see any affordances for that on the blog. How should we submit this sort of feedback?

Comment: Struggling to wrap my brain around the "determined" point, I didn't have any issue reading it as active (especially considering the sentence starts with "To address this")

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. Who will review the suggested edits? How to prevent abuse?

Comment: @GammaGames That point only threw me for a second (I exaggerated it for illustration), but the CEO announcements are very dense in comprehension speed-bumps like this. (I suspect they're made by pasting together lots of bits written by lots of different people, then smoothing out the grammar.) It would be clearer as “Stack Overflow's been determinedly addressing this by…” – but that sentence has other bits that I don't quite get the meaning of (e.g. I'm not sure what it means for AI offerings to be “attributed in the knowledge base”) or that are grammatically ambiguous (the last three 'and's).

Answer (score 4):

If you're logged in to Stack Overflow, there's an option at the bottom:

[image]

I report typos and such all the time via similar ways on various Internet sites. The comments on the Stack Overflow blog never appear right away (at least, that has been my experience), so the employees who moderate them may not approve such comments for publishing, but instead make the necessary copy-editing to the blog post.

If the author has a Stack Exchange account, it may be an option to leave a comment on one of their network posts. I have never done that, but I recall somebody commenting on one of my X.SE posts about a typo in one of my Y.SE posts (where they were not a member), which I definitely appreciated.

<sup>(this post is answering the final sentence "How should we submit this sort of feedback?" - I only realized you asked a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) later on ...)</sup>

Comment: You can use moderated comments as sort of flags? That is staggeringly obvious in hindsight.

Comment: At least, it's worth a try ...

Comment: I only tagged it [tag:feature-request] because I didn't think there _was_ a way (and flooding meta with "please correct this typo" doesn't seem very polite). “This feature already exists” is a valid frame challenge to a feature request, in my book.

Comment: tbf, there have been posts on meta asking for corrections to specific blog posts that have been successful.

Comment: Yes, the ones I remember most vividly are the technical corrections about encoding problems :)